# Solutions to avoid re-writing the same location in memory?

Tags: c, memory

```c
void scan(Scanner *scanner) {
    // Initialise the scanner
    int length_of_src = strlen(scanner->source);
    scanner->tokens = malloc(sizeof(Token) * length_of_src + 1);

    int *line = &scanner->line;
    *line = 1;

    int *column = &scanner->column;
    *column = 0;
    char *ch = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1);

    for (; *column < length_of_src; (*column)++) {
        *ch = scanner->source[*column];
        identify_token(scanner, ch);
    }

    Token eof_token = { END_OF_FILE, "EOF", "EOF", *line };
    scanner->tokens[NUM_TOKENS + 1] = eof_token;
}
```

So I have this piece of code and the main focus is on `char *ch = ...` and `identify_token()` this is what it looks like.

```c
void identify_token(Scanner *scanner, char *ch) {
    TokenType token_type;
    // NOTE: When updating the switch case
    // update TokenName token_names[] as well.
    switch (*ch) {
    case '(':
        token_type = LEFT_PAREN;
        break;
    // other cases...
    default:
        // TODO: Implement error handling.
        printf("Unexpected token.\n");
        return;
    }

    Token token = { token_type, ch, ch, scanner->line };
    scanner->tokens[NUM_TOKENS] = token;
    NUM_TOKENS++;
}
```

As for `scanner->source` is made like this:

```c
    char *source = "((,)).*"; // 7 chars + 1 null byte
    Scanner *scanner = malloc(sizeof(Scanner));
    // Creates memory for source
    scanner->source = malloc(strlen(source));
    strcpy(scanner->source, source);
```

This is what `Token` is.

```c
typedef struct Token {
    TokenType type;
    // The character that represents the TokenType
    char *lexeme;
    // The value to be evaluated.
    // To convert with *(type *)token.literal
    void *literal;
    int line;
} Token;
```

In the for-loop inside `scan`, I pass `ch` to `identify_token` in every iteration. However, the value in the memory location of `ch` is constantly updated, and the previous value is overwritten and lost. What I want is

1. Have the old value be saved.
2. Keep the new value as well.

So, with the current code the result is that whatever is the current character in the for-loop, `lexeme` in `Token` will be that character. So, when the loop is finished `lexeme` will be the last character in `scanner->source` which is `*` in this case.

[image]

So, when I inspect the values in `gdb` this is what I get.

I was suggested that the solution to the problem is dynamic allocation and from the searching I can find the line `char *ch = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1);`  counts as dynamic allocation. So, I'm missing something but not sure what.

I'm not too sure what I can do, the only thing I've tried is that instead of this

```c
Token token = { token_type, ch, ch, scanner->line };
```

I have

```
Token token = { token_type, scanner->source[scanner->column], ch, scanner->line };
```

Just to test out and see if it would work. However, there are two problems.

1. `scanner->source[scanner->column]` is incorrect because `Token` wants a pointer. To fix that I add a `&` in the front.
2. But that produces the entire string, not just that character. So `token.lexeme` would be `scanner->source`.

I'm not sure if it is relevant, but I feel it necessary to say that in the future I plan to include `lexeme`s that are longer than just one character. For example, "var", "return", etc.

So the main question is what can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: `char *ch = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1)`? Why? For a single character that just doesn't make any sense. Also note that the C specification say that `sizeof(char)` will *always* be `1`.

Comment: And `scanner->source = malloc(strlen(source));` is problematic. Firstly because you don't allocate space for the string terminator; Secondly because you don't actually copy the string.

Comment: Generally, there's just too many pointers in your code. Most of them are just not needed.

Comment: Dynamic memory allocation is a means to an end, not, for the most part, a solution (to anything) in and of itself.

Comment: Possibly the [`strndup()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strndup) function would be of use to you.  Or if your standard library happens not to provide that (even with the appropriate feature-test macro definition) then it's not too hard to implement the same or similar yourself.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude as for `malloc` with the `char` I'll make the fix, thanks. As for allocating for `scanner->source` I didn't realise I didn't give the full code, I did use `strcpy` to copy `source` to `scanner->source`. And as for not allocating for the string terminator, when I do `printf` for `scanner->source`, from what I can tell it is properly terminated because I don't get any garbage values after the `*`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude as for too many pointers, is one of them `*column`, and `*line`?

Comment: The `strcpy` call *will* add the terminator. Out of bounds of your allocated memory. Which leads to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 0):

From the fragments of source code, it seems the `lexeme` field of the `Token` structure should point to the source string at the point where the lexeme starts and the `literal` field should point to an allocated object whose type depends on the type of token found.

`identify_token` should receive a pointer to the source string, and this pointer can be stored to the `lexeme` field of the new token, and the function should have a way to tell its caller how many bytes the token uses in the source string so the scanner can advance to the next token.  For example `(` is a single byte token `LEFT_PAREN`, `a` could be a single byte token `CHAR` whose value in `literal` should be a pointer to a 1 byte string `"a"` and `\(` is a 2 byte token `CHAR` whose `literal` points to a 1 byte string `"("`.

Here is a modified version you can study:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef enum TokenType {
    END_OF_FILE, ERROR, LEFT_PAREN, RIGHT_PAREN, COMMA, DOT, STAR, QUESTION, NEW_LINE, CHAR, STRING,
} TokenType;

typedef struct Token {
    TokenType type;
    // The character that represents the TokenType
    const char *lexeme;
    // The value to be evaluated.
    // To convert with *(type *)token.literal
    void *literal;
    int line;
} Token;

typedef struct Scanner {
    char *source;
    int line, column;
    int num_tokens;
    struct Token *tokens;
} Scanner;

int identify_token(Scanner *scanner, char *ch) {
    Token token = { ERROR, ch, NULL, scanner->line };
    int len = 1;
    switch (*ch) {
    case '(':
        token.type = LEFT_PAREN;
        break;
    case ')':
        token.type = RIGHT_PAREN;
        break;
    case ',':
        token.type = COMMA;
        break;
    case '.':
        token.type = DOT;
        break;
    case '*':
        token.type = STAR;
        break;
    case '?':
        token.type = QUESTION;
        break;
    case '\\':  // escape special character
        token.type = CHAR;
        token.literal = strndup(ch + 1, 1);
        len = 2;
        break;
    case '\n':
        token.type = NEW_LINE;
        scanner->line++;
        scanner->column = -len;
        break;
        // other cases...
    default:
        len = strcspn(ch, "(),.*?\\\n");
        if (len > 1) {
            token.type = STRING;
            token.literal = strndup(ch, len);
        } else {
            token.type = CHAR;
            token.literal = strndup(ch, 1);
        }
        break;
    }
    scanner->tokens[scanner->num_tokens++] = token;
    scanner->column += len;
    return len;
}

void scan(Scanner *scanner, const char *src) {
    // Initialise the scanner
    int length_of_src = strlen(src);
    scanner->source = strdup(src);
    scanner->tokens = malloc(sizeof(Token) * length_of_src + 1);
    scanner->num_tokens = 0;
    scanner->line = 1;
    scanner->column = 0;

    for (int pos = 0; pos < length_of_src;) {
        pos += identify_token(scanner, scanner->source + pos);
    }

    Token eof_token = { END_OF_FILE, scanner->source + length_of_src, strdup("EOF"), scanner->line };
    scanner->tokens[scanner->num_tokens++] = eof_token;
}

void print_token(Token token) {
    switch (token.type) {
    case END_OF_FILE:
        printf("<END>");
        break;
    case LEFT_PAREN:
        printf("(");
        break;
    case RIGHT_PAREN:
        printf(")");
        break;
    case COMMA:
        printf(",");
        break;
    case DOT:
        printf(".");
        break;
    case STAR:
        printf("*");
        break;
    case QUESTION:
        printf("?");
        break;
    case CHAR:
        printf("'%c'", *(char *)token.literal);
        break;
    case STRING:
        printf("\"%s\"", (char *)token.literal);
        break;
    case NEW_LINE:
        printf("'\n'");
        break;
    case ERROR:
        printf("ERROR");
        break;
    }
}

void free_scanner(Scanner *scanner) {
    free(scanner->source);
    for (int i = 0; i < scanner->num_tokens; i++) {
        free(scanner->tokens[i].literal);
    }
    free(scanner->tokens);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const char *source = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "((,)).*";
    Scanner *scanner = calloc(sizeof(Scanner), 1);
    scan(scanner, source);
    for (int i = 0; i < scanner->num_tokens; i++) {
        print_token(scanner->tokens[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    free_scanner(scanner);
    free(scanner);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Instead of figuring out how many bytes a token is, can't you look at the next character in the source string and then use an if statement to check if the string matches some format so the appropriate `Token` can be made? As that is the approach I plan on taking.